# Feature matching metal object with SIFT, SURF, or ORB

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, surf, homography

I'm trying to identify keypoint features in my image, which is taken looking directly at my object, then try and match those keypoint features to an image of the same object that has been slightly tilted. My goal is to identify the rotation required to move from one image to next and vice versa.

[image]
[image]

The problem I'm having is the matching process for key points is completely inaccurate. From my understanding, this is because my object is fairly uniform in color, symmetrical, and how it reflects light makes the process difficult.

Is there any way I can improve the SIFT or ORB feature matching?

Or is there another method that would work better for my given application. I'm relatively new to computer vision and would appreciate any advice.

Here is the code I'm working with. I've been referencing OpenCV docs and online tutorials so far.

```
try:
   surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)
except Exception:
   surf = cv2.cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(400)

kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

img_pts = cv2.drawKeypoints(img1, kp1, None)
plt.imshow(img_pts)
plt.show()

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)


# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

match_results = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good[:], None, flags=2)
plt.imshow(match_results)
plt.show()


MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

    # see https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html for details
    ss = M[0, 1]
    sc = M[0, 0]
    scaleRecovered = np.sqrt(ss * ss + sc * sc)
    thetaRecovered = np.arctan2(ss, sc) * 180 / np.pi
    print('Scale: {} , Rotation: {}'.format(scaleRecovered, thetaRecovered))

    # deskew image
    im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, np.linalg.inv(M),
                                     (img1.shape[1], img1.shape[0]))

    plt.title('Before')
    plt.imshow(img1)
    plt.show()

    plt.title('After')
    plt.imshow(im_out)
    plt.show()

    plt.title('compare')
    plt.imshow(img2)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I assume you are right that SIFT/SURF/... are not ideal for this task. They all rely on having the surrounding of keypoints look sufficiently similar under changes of perspective. You may get usable results if you can manage to get a more pure ambient light environment.

Comment: May be you can try to match the images in a different color space which isn't influenced by ambient light as much as BGR/RGB is.

Comment: In this lighting condition, object nature/color and variance of perspective will be hard for this algorithms to extract consistent features and even harder to match them. Question: Can you alter the object? A man-made landmark (Bar, Aztec, QR Codes) is way easier to track an re-project!  (https://github.com/MikhailGordeev/QR-Code-Extractor)

Comment: Ideally, we can not modify the object, but I'm coming to the realization that we might have to. To do so I'm looking into doing that with aruco markers. The color changes over time as well as the lighting so we need some that is illumination invariant, scale, and rotation invariant. The mounting location of this object also changes. Ideally, we need a general matching algorithim that could be robust enough in various environments.

Comment: Essentially, the question is whether you want to put more effort into data acquisition (add markers, change lighting) or into a more sophisticated algorithm. You may also have more success if the rotation between two consecutive frames is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right path. However, why not use a ready tool? For example, see ORB Slam, CNN-SLam:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufvPS5wJAx0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_NJxbkQnBU

They all do a similar process of what you have been trying to do. I believe ORB Slam uses ORB matchers. What they have different than you?

- Stereo camera works better then mono
- They take lots of pictures (or use video feed) with each picture having small angular differences
- The camera most of the time has an gyro/accelerator so, they use that data to kind of guess how the camera moves and combine that with what it sees. (Sensor fusion)
- 3D point cloud is closed on itself to provide a physically sound environment.

If you want to try it yourself, know that blind homography matching will never give you good results. The reasons for that are the ones you've listed / listed on comments of your question. However, you can follow up on the ideas of those libraries and come up a similar implementation of your own, or you can modify them according to your needs (which will be better if you even improved them so that we all can use :-))